# Webkit browser border-radius doesn't "cut" inner elements

Tags: css, webkit, parent-child

Many elements inside others with a border radius do not get "cut" inside the element. I have a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite very simple. 

No guarantees, however. This at least worked for me:

`opacity:0.99;`

should work in css. It is quite simple, and does not affect it's opacity much!

****Note:**** Setting the opacity to 1 will NOT work. you  must put it to a value < 1.